# Python mock, expected str instance MagicMock found

Tags: python, django, python-mock

I am trying to use Mock with Django for two things:
1. Get a user (we have a custom backend that makes network calls that I want
to avoid)
2. Mock out another method that gets a token for password resets over the network.

Here is the test:

```
@patch('core.views.KagisoUser')
def test_forgot_password_sends_reset_email(self, MockKagisoUser):  # noqa
    email = 'mock@user.com'
    user = MagicMock()
    user.email = email
    user.generate_reset_password_token.return_value = email
    MockKagisoUser.objects.first.return_value = user
    data = {'email': email}
    client = Client()

    response = client.post('/forgot_password/', data, follow=True)
    message = list(response.context['messages'])[0].message

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert 'You will receive an email with reset instructions shortly' \
        == message

    assert len(mail.outbox) == 1
    assert mail.outbox[0].to[0] == email
    assert mail.outbox[0].subject == 'Password Reset'
    assert mail.outbox[0].alternatives[0]  # HTML body
```

I get this error:

```
self = <django.core.mail.message.EmailMultiAlternatives object at 0x7f52eacd3390>

        def message(self):
            encoding = self.encoding or settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
            msg = SafeMIMEText(self.body, self.content_subtype, encoding)
            msg = self._create_message(msg)
            msg['Subject'] = self.subject
            msg['From'] = self.extra_headers.get('From', self.from_email)
    >       msg['To'] = self.extra_headers.get('To', ', '.join(self.to))
    E       TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, MagicMock found
```

Here is the implementation:

```
def forgot_password(request):
    reset_message = 'You will receive an email with reset instructions shortly'
    not_found_message = 'We could not find a user for that email address'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ForgotPasswordForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user = KagisoUser.objects.filter(email=email).first()

            if user:
                print(user.email)
                token = user.generate_reset_password_token()
                url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('reset_password'))
                message = render_to_string(
                    'core/emails/reset_password.html',
                    {
                        'url': url,
                        'token': token,
                        'user_id': user.id
                    }
                )
                send_mail(
                    'Password Reset',
                    '',
                    'development@kagiso.io',
                    [user.email],
                    html_message=message
                )
                messages.success(request, reset_message)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, not_found_message)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('forgot_password'))
    else:
        form = forms.ForgotPasswordForm()

    return render(
        request,
        'core/auth/forgot_password.html',
        {'form': form}
    )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stack trace would be really useful...

but besides that it seems you mocker out `MockKagisoUser.objects.first` whereas your view gets the user from `KagisoUser.objects.filter(email=email).first()` so you're missing `filter`

```
mock_filter = MagicMock()
mock_filter.first.return_value = user
MockKagisoUser.objects.filter.return_value = mock_filter
```

the above should return you a filter that will return your user when getting `first` which in turn will return your user in your view rather than returning MagicMock instance